# System tray context menu doesn't disappear

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I create a notification icon with:

```
notifyIcon.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
notifyIcon.hWnd   = mainWnd;
notifyIcon.uID    = 100;
notifyIcon.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP | NIF_MESSAGE;
notifyIcon.hIcon  = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_LOGO));
notifyIcon.dwState = NIS_SHAREDICON;
notifyIcon.uVersion = NOTIFYICON_VERSION;
notifyIcon.uTimeout = 15000;
notifyIcon.uCallbackMessage = APP_MSG_TRAY;
wcscpy_s(notifyIcon.szTip, 127, WTXT_APP_TRAY_TOOLTIP);

Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &notifyIcon);
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_SETVERSION, &notifyIcon);
```

And have a context menu popup on WM_RBUTTONDOWN and WM_CONTEXTMENU like this:

```
MENUITEMINFO separatorBtn = {0};
separatorBtn.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
separatorBtn.fMask = MIIM_FTYPE;
separatorBtn.fType = MFT_SEPARATOR;

HMENU hMenu = CreatePopupMenu();

if(hMenu) {
 InsertMenu(hMenu, -1, MF_BYPOSITION, APP_OPEN_OPTIONS, WTXT_OPTIONS);
 InsertMenuItem(hMenu, -1, FALSE, &separatorBtn);
 InsertMenu(hMenu, -1, MF_BYPOSITION, APP_MSG_EXIT, WTXT_EXIT);

 POINT pt;
 GetCursorPos(&pt);
 SetForegroundWindow(mainWnd);
 TrackPopupMenu(hMenu, TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, pt.x, pt.y, 0, mainWnd, NULL);
 PostMessage(mainWnd, WM_NULL, 0, 0);
 DestroyMenu(hMenu);
}
```

It works fine, but the context menu doesn't disappear always. Sometimes (often) if you have ie. winamp and my app icons in system tray, if you right click my app and winamp afterwards, bot menus will appear, and my menu won't disappear automatically until you click an item.

Any ideas?

thanks...

Comment: I've noticed this frequently with lots of other applications too, like Spybot and AVG.  I wonder if it's actually a Win32 bug or misfeature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not catch WM_RBUTTONDOWN but WM_RBUTTONUP. And of course do not handle both WM_RBUTTONUP and WM_CONTEXTMENU, since they will **both** get handled and you'd show the context menu twice for every right-click.
Showing the menu twice would have the effect you describe: the menu shows up, but doesn't seem to disappear (because it shows up again right away a second time).

Comment: thanks, i'll give it a try tomorrow and get back to you. I think this could help, because the same issue arises if i click very fast on my apps icon - two menus appear.

Answer (score 16):

To display a context menu for a notification icon, the current window must be the foreground window before the application calls TrackPopupMenu or TrackPopupMenuEx. Otherwise, the menu will not disappear when the user clicks outside of the menu or the window that created the menu (if it is visible).

```
SetForegroundWindow(hDlg);

TrackPopupMenu(   hSubMenu,
                 TPM_RIGHTBUTTON,
                 pt.x,
                 pt.y,
                 0,
                 hDlg,
                 NULL);
```

Comment: 6 years later, seriously? :)

Comment: I do not care about the time, just to solve this problem, ha ha

Comment: Really thank you for this, it works!!! The bug happens for me in Qt/QML application and was a real enigma

Comment: This insightful answer should be added into the accepted one.

Comment: In my case it makes no difference whether the main dialog is visible or not. Simply clicking away from the system tray menu does not make it go away still.

Answer (score 1):

There are apps to try to hack around the restrictions of the notification area (tray) API.  They'll hook the Explorer window and listen for Windows messages.  That lets them do stuff that isn't otherwise possible but it inevitably destabilizes other apps.  Getting two context menus is a sure sign of this kind of trouble.

You've got a good lead on what kind of program may do this, it's got an icon.  Kill them one by one until you find the evil-doer.  Not much you can do about it probably, other than not running it or complaining to the vendor.

Comment: this bug of mine arises no matter which applications are involved (windows included), so i'd guess it's either a problem stefan suggested or a windows bug...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to already have both of the documented bugfixes (SetForegroundWindow & WM_NULL) I'd say anything beyond this is a bug in windows.

If you really want to do hacky things, you could probably get the menu window handle in WM_INITMENU* (And I don't mean the HMENU, but the HWND for the menu) and hide that window.

Comment: well, my boss wants it resolved, so if stefan's fix doesn't solve the issue i'll have to do this, thanks